# Marshalling an empty void* parameter that can take multiple structure and retrieving it in C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, unmanaged, managed

I want to call a C function with an empty void* parameter and retrieve it in C# to print the struct values.

In this example:

1. The C code will randomly assign one of the two structures to the void parameter.
2. The C code return must be an int.
3. The C code structures can be modified

How to retrieve and print the C struct content in C#?

C

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void PrintKdesc(interTICKeyDescription* kdescr)
{
    kdescr->nItems++;
    printf("nItems = %d\n", kdescr->nItems);
}

void PrintKevent(interTICEvent* kevent)
{
    kevent->nbr++;
    printf("nbr = %d\n", kevent->nbr);
}

EXPORT int VoidPtrTest(void* test)
{
    interTICKeyDescription kdesc = { 1, 0x250021, 0, 42 };
    interTICEvent kevent = { 2, 8 };

    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() % 2;
    if (r == 1)
    {
        test = &kdesc;
        PrintKdesc(test);
    }
    else
    {
        test = &kevent;
        PrintKevent(test);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

```
typedef struct {
    int          id;
    unsigned int networkId;
    unsigned int implVersion;
    int          nItems;
} interTICKeyDescription;

typedef struct {
    int          id;
    int          nbr;
} interTICEvent;
```

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct InterTICKeyDescription
{
    public int id;
    public UInt32 networkId;
    public UInt32 implVersion;
    public int nItems;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct InterTICEvent
{
    public int id;
    public int nbr;
}
```

```
[DllImport("Sandbox.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
extern static int VoidPtrTest(IntPtr test);
```

My attempt

```
        static void Main()
        {
            InterTICKeyDescription kdesc = new InterTICKeyDescription();
            InterTICEvent kevent = new InterTICEvent();
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(kdesc));

            VoidPtrTest(ptr);

            int id = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr, 0);
            if (id == 1)
            {
                kdesc = (InterTICKeyDescription)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(InterTICKeyDescription));
                Console.WriteLine("Id 1: " + kdesc.nItems);
            }
            else
            {
                kevent = (InterTICEvent)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(InterTICEvent));
                Console.WriteLine("Id 2: " + kevent.nbr);
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
```

Comment: Two problems: (1) `test = &kdesc;` only changes `VoidPtrTest`'s `test` parameter (which acts as a local variable). You would need to declare `test` as `void **test`, pass the address of a `void *` to the function, and use `*test = &kdesc;` to fix that. (2) `kdesc` and `kevent` have `auto` storage class (i.e. "on the stack"). They cease to exist when the function returns, so any pointer to them will become invalid when the function returns.

Comment: Apart from: Please don't place parentheses around return values; `return` is not a function. If you ever switch to C++ there's even a situation where the parentheses can produce a dangling reference.

Comment: Your C `interTICKeyDescription` and `interTICEvent` types have an extra member `int id;` that is not present in the C# types. Also, the return value of `VoidPtrTest` is being ignored.

Comment: @IanAbbott Sorry for the typo, post updated. Passing a void** is fine for me, but since the structs stop to exists when the function return, is there any other way around to make it work?

Comment: @Aconcagua Having the return between parentheses was actually a requirement from my programming school lol, that is very good to know!

Comment: Do you want `VoidPtrTest` to fill in a block of memory pre-allocated by the caller, or do you want it to allocate its own block of memory and pass a pointer back to the caller?

Comment: @IanAbbott Both of these options are valid in my current context, althought my objective here is to add the least amount of modification to the C code.

Comment: The easiest option would be to change `test = &kdesc;` to `memcpy(test, &kdesc, sizeof kdesc);` (and similarly for `&kevent`), and change `return (0);` to `return r;`. There is no need for the `id` member - just set the `id` variable in the C# code to the return value of the function, i.e. `int id = VoidPtrTest(ptr);`. (Note: `#include <string.h>` to declare `memcpy`.)

Comment: @IanAbbott Everything is working perfectly with memcpy, I've been stuck on this problem for days! Thank you very much Ian. The int return is used to return different kind of errors in the original code, hence why I wrote the 2. and used "id" in the structs